# Condensing multiple onclicks into one

Tags: javascript, dom-events, oneclick

This is my current code:

```
document.getElementsByName('links')[0].onclick = function (event) {
event = event || window.event;
var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {index: link, event: event},
    links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};

document.getElementsByName('links')[1].onclick = function (event) {
event = event || window.event;
var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {index: link, event: event},
    links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
```

I realize that this copy and pasting is terribly inefficient (and would only get worse when I need to add `[2].onclick`, `[3].onclick`, etc.), so is there a way I could condense all of them together?

I'm a beginner when it comes to Javascript, so please forgive me if this question is extremely simple.

Comment: why dont you use jquery?

Comment: Give your function a name and define it once. Then, you can do `var links = document.getElementsByName('links'); for( var i=0, l = links.length; i<l; i++) links[i].onclick = theFunctionYouNamed;`

Comment: Thank you, Niet, your solution also works and is easy to understand intuitively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery aside, all you need to do is encapsulate the duplicated code, e.g:

```
<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByName('links');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
    el.onclick = function (event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
            link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
            options = {index: link, event: event},
            links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
        blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
    };
});
</script>
```